# Migrating User Profiles/Merging User Accounts in Two AD Domains

Tags: active-directory, migration, admt

We have two domains in separate forests and need to merge/migrate them. I believe a simple migration with ADMT will move all the local user profiles over, and will not be a problem. The potential problem is that all the users in domain2, have identical user accounts (same user/pass) in domain1 so that they can have exchange mailboxes.

If we do a migration with ADMT, will we have any issues since the users need to be merged, whereas computers and local profiles need to be migrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have an issue with this. Each step of the migration can have a different action. You can **migrate** computers and **merge** users without issue.

Comment: Thanks. Alas, we haven't done it yet, but it's nice to know it should all go smoothly.